# is there an official helm for Redis Cluster?

Tags: redis

I am considering Redis to support caching in our application.

I was wondering, wouldn't most production setups with Kubernetes need multiple masters?

Helm lists Redis and Redis-ha, with the second providing HA but not clustering/partitioning.

Is there another helm chart or popular operator that actually implements Redis clustering?

Thank you!